# Compare two excel sheets and writing output to different tab/excel sheet

Tags: excel, compare, multiple-columns

I have two excel sheets a.xls and b.xls. a.xls contains single column(contains employee Id's) and b.xls with two columns (contains employee Id's and Employee names). I need to compare a.xls values with b.xls and copy the matching values to another excel sheet. I.e., if a.xls employee id matches with b.xls employee id, i want output of that employee id and employee name from b.xls to another excel sheet or in another tab in same excel sheet also works. Any ideas.

Thanks,
Jagadeesh.K

Comment: This is precisely what the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is designed to do.

Comment: seems VLOOKUP give value for one value and if you need more you need manually enter it to see corresponding output. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean you have duplicate employee IDs?  If so, then you are correct, VLOOKUP will only return the first match.  Also, you should not have duplicate employee IDs.

Comment: Its not duplicate. one excel sheet contains set of employees and another excel sheet contains all employee id's with their names. So, all am trying to do is check employee from a.xls with b.xls and if matches get employee names from b.xls and store it new excel sheet

Comment: VLOOKUP does exactly that.  If you're running into problems, please edit your question and provide sample data, the formula you're using, and what the expected and actual results are.